# restriction on axioms in system QS

Tags: first-order-logic, metalogic

In the system QS we have the following axiom

$$(A \to \forall vA)$$
if $v$ does not occur free in $A$.

This more or less feels intuitive however the explanation given in the text is confusing me.  The text is Metalogic by Hunter (page 167).

> The reason for the restriction on this axiom is that without it we should have the following formula, for example, as an axiom:
>
> $$Fx_1 \to \forall x_1 Fx_1$$
>
> That formula is not logically valid. (Take the domain $D$ as the set of natural numbers and $'F'$ as 'is even'.  Then the sequence $\langle 2,2,2,\ldots \rangle$, for example, does not satisfy the formula.

The issue I have is....  I'm not sure why the sequence does not satisfy the formula. Is $x_1$ a sequence or the first element of the sequence.  If the latter then clearly $2$ is even but not just any number is even, obviously.  If the former, then in what sense is a sequence 'even'.  Well....  I clearly don't understand what's going on, because this should be straight forward.  Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the formula $Fx_1 → ∀x_1Fx_1$ is **not** *valid* ?

Valid means: true in every interpretation with every variable assignment.

Consider the following interpretation; domain $\mathbb N$ and the predicate $Fx$ interpreted as "$x$ is *even*".

The sequnce $s = \langle 2,2,\dots \rangle$ satisfies $Fx_1$, because it assigns the value $2$ to $x_1$, and $2$ is *even*, but it does not satisfies $∀x_1Fx_1$.

This is so [see [page 147](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&pg=PA147)] because **not** every sequence differing from $s$ at most for the value assigned to $x_1$ satisfies $Fx_1$: consider the sequence $s'= \langle 3,2,\dots \rangle$.

In conclusion, we have found an interpretation and a variable assignment such that the *antecedent* of the formula is *true* while the *consequent* is *false*, and thus such that the formula is *false*.

---

Obviously, we want that the logical axiom schema produce only *valid* instances; this is the reason for the restriction on $x$ not being *free* in axiom schema:

> $A \to \forall v A$.